# how to use imshow with new set_aspect and clim?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used to be able to create 2d plots with

```
x=np.linspace(0,1,5)
y=np.linspace(1,100,5)
img=np.ones([len(x),len(y)])*500
plt.imshow(img,extent=(x[0], x[-1], y[-1], y[0]))
plt.axes().set_aspect(0.06)
plt.clim(0,500)
plt.show()
```

Now, set aspect gives me a blank image (same as here: https://cloudstack.ninja/xotix/plt-axes-set_aspectequal-destroys-plot-by-adding-a-lot-of-white-space/)

If I try to use the ax. style of plot, I can no longer use plt.clim(0,500):

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(img,extent=(x[0], x[-1], y[-1], y[0]))
### ax.set_clim(0,500) # not a function
ax.set_xlabel('$t$ [ns]')
ax.set_ylabel('$\lambda$ [nm]')
ax.set_aspect(0.06)
ax.set_xlim(5,11)
ax.set_ylim(351,290)
fig.show()
```

Is there another replacement for set_clim here?  I have been looking but could not find anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Plt.axes makes a new axes.  You want plt.gca()

Answer (score 0):

You can give `clim` as a kwarg when you call `imshow`, for example:

```
im = ax.imshow(img,extent=(x[0], x[-1], y[-1], y[0]), clim=(0, 500))
```

Alternatively, if you capture the `AxesImage` returned by `imshow` in a variable (here I call it `im`), you can use `im.set_clim()` to set the `clim` on it later.

```
im = ax.imshow(img,extent=(x[0], x[-1], y[-1], y[0]))
im.set_clim(0, 500)
```

And, as @Jody Klymak pointed out in the comments, the reason your first option doesn't work is because `plt.axes()` creates a new Axes instance. You could use `plt.gca().set_aspect(0.06)` in place there instead